# Why is the x509 standard for certificates called "x509"? What is meaning behind "x" and/or "509"?

Tags: tls, x.509

X509 is the name of the [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) which defines Public Key Infrastructure and the format of SSL/TLS Certificates. My question is:  *What does **x509** mean?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X.509 is a standard number/index defined by [ITU-T](https://www.itu.int), telecommunication and standartization commitee.

**X** stands for [Data networks, open system communications and security](https://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/index.aspx?ser=X) standards track and every standard has a number. X.500-X.599 standards define directory services (such as DAP, LDAP, etc.). And [509](https://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=14033) is just a number of standard in X track.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you so much!  -- Do you by chance know why certain numbers were skipped?  (502-508, 512-517, etc)

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia:

> X.509 was initially issued on July 3, 1988 and was begun in association with the X.500 standard.

> X.500 is a series of computer networking standards covering electronic
> directory services. The X.500 series was developed by the
> Telecommunication Standardization Sector of the International
> Telecommunications Union (ITU-T). ITU-T was formerly known as the
> Consultative Committee for International Telephony and Telegraphy
> (CCITT).
>
> X.500 was approved first in 1988.[1] The directory services were
> developed to support requirements of **X.400** electronic mail exchange
> and name lookup. The International Organization for Standardization
> (ISO) was a partner in developing the standards, incorporating them
> into the Open Systems Interconnection suite of protocols. ISO/IEC 9594
> is the corresponding ISO identification.

> X.400 is a suite of ITU-T Recommendations that defines the ITU-T
> Message Handling System (MHS).

I could not find why X.400 is named X.400 though, also why X509 and not X.502.